# Percentage of failures in dc.js

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

How to calculate % of failure i.e count where the failure occurred/total count ??

```
Customer | Year| Week |Failure     |       name        |    Type  |   Count 
___________________________________________________________________________
A         2018  29       N              Express Air       PASSENGER      27
___________________________________________________________________________
A         2018  26       N              Express Air       PASSENGER      58
___________________________________________________________________________
A         2018  26   Delay hours        Express Air                       5
___________________________________________________________________________
A         2018  27       N              Express Air       HIGH SPEED     29
___________________________________________________________________________
A         2018  30  Maintenance missed  Express Air       PASSENGER      11
___________________________________________________________________________
A         2018  32      N               Express Air       PASSENGER      53
___________________________________________________________________________
A         2018  25      N               Express Air                       2
___________________________________________________________________________
A        2018   33      N               Express Air       HIGH SPEED      3
____________________________________________________________________________
A        2018   31  Bogey Missing       Express Air       PASSENGER       1
```

This is my datatable created with dc.js and crossfilter

```
        var ndx= crossfilter(data);
        var all= ndx.groupAll();  
        var countType = ndx.dimension(function (d) { return d["count"]; }); 
        dataTable.width(800).height(800)
        .dimension(countType)
        .group(function(d) { return "" })
        .size(100)
        .columns([
            function(d) { return d.alias; },
            function(d) { return d.y; },
            function(d) { return d.w; },
            function(d) { return d.failure_reason; },
            function(d) { return d.name; },
            function(d) { return d.train_type; },
            function(d) { return d.count; }
        ])
        .sortBy(function(d){ return d.count; })
        // (optional) sort order, :default ascending
        .order(d3.descending);
```

**EDIT: Just small changes, got the total sum working**

```
         var total = countType.groupAll().reduceSum(function(d) {return 
         d["count"];})
         dc.numberDisplay("#total")
         .valueAccessor(function(d){return d})
         .group(total);
```

**For calculating % where no failure occurred (N)**
Here I could calculate where failure_type was 'N' , how to calculate % of failure of all other type except N

```
         var failureGroup= failureType.group().reduceSum(function(d) {return 
         d.count;});
         var failureType = ndx.dimension(function(d) { return 
         d["failure_reason"]; });
         function choose_bin(group, key) {
          return {
            value: function() {
              return group.all().filter(kv => kv.key === key)[0].value;
            }
          }
        }  
        var allCount = failureType.groupAll().reduceSum(d => d.count);
        var nofailure = choose_bin(failureGroup, 'N');

        dc.numberDisplay("#total1")
        .group(nofailure)
        .valueAccessor(x => (x / allCount.value())*100);
```

Comment: Seems that earlier question doesn't provide any answer. But `numberDisplay` is a good start - only thing is you'd want to use a [groupAll](https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference#crossfilter_groupAll) instead of an ordinary group. I think [this example shows good ways to show a sum and average](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/number.html) in a `numberDisplay`, could you take a look and revise your question if you're still stuck?

Comment: Got the Total sum working, Thanks Gordon.

Comment: Hi Gordon, for calculating the percentage, I used one method recommended by you, I have edited the post above. But how do I group all failure except 'N' as mentioned in line "var nofailure = choose_bin(failureGroup, 'N');"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could probably get it working with groups and bins as you've shown, but it's a bit simpler just to use `groupAll` again:

```
    var allCount = failureType.groupAll().reduceSum(d => d.count);
    var nofailure = failureType.groupAll()
        .reduceSum(d => d.failure_reason === 'N' ? d.count : 0);
    dc.numberDisplay("#total1")
        .group(nofailure)
        .valueAccessor(x => (x / allCount.value())*100);
```